# How do i click on a web button that appears multiple times on a page and how do I click on all of them?

Tags: vbscript, automation, qtp

I am testing a web page and specifically a web button. In order to get a helping answer I'll provide all of the information I can on it. I am specifically testing the "Like" button on a website (Webstagram.com) that is meant for you to view and operate your Instagram page from your desktop. 20 different pictures are displayed on a page and each picture has its own "like" button assigned to it. I can't identify it by "like" and in the outerhtml there are different values for each one. How do I write a script to identify each one. Please help I would GREATLY  APRECIATE IT!!

Comment: Can you post the HTML source? there should be some property to identity them!

Comment: @Vinoth S yea here is some of the info on the properties/values. 

class: btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton

htmlid: N/a

htmltag: Button

innerhtml: <I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like

outterhtml (Like button for pic #1)  <BUTTON class="btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton" type=button data-target="1194558981914665301_8054519"><I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like</BUTTON>

outerhtml (like button for pic#2)    <BUTTON class="btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton" type=button data-target="1194558967727891183_339837919"><I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like</BUTTON>

Comment: Have you used descriptive programming in qtp?

Comment: NOTE*  i listed the outerhtml property values for two different pictures to show you wear the values differ. this is also the outerhtml code i tried to write to to order it to click on any like button and bypass any specific values:

outerhtml: <BUTTON class="btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton" type=button data-target=".*_.*"><I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like</BUTTON> 

this is the script that i tried to use to execute it and it failed:

Comment: 1) systemutil.Run "http://websta.me/tag/graffiti"

2) Browser("#graffiti Instagram photos").Page("#graffiti Instagram photos").WebButton("<BUTTON class="btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton" type=button data-target=".*_.*"><I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like</BUTTON> ").Click

3)wait(1)

4) Browser("#graffiti Instagram photos").Page("#graffiti Instagram photos").WebButton("<BUTTON class="btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton" type=button data-target=".*_.*"><I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like</BUTTON> ").Click

5) wait(1)

repeat...

Comment: @VinothS what do you think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please Help!! how do i click on a web button that appears muiltiple times on a webpage? how do i click all of them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762562/please-help-how-do-i-click-on-a-web-button-that-appears-muiltiple-times-on-a-w)