# How do I click on a web button that appears multiple times on a webpage?

Tags: automation, qtp

How do I click on a web button that appears multiple times on a webpage? How do I click all of them?

I am testing the "Like" button on a website (Webstagram.com) that is meant for you to view and operate your Instagram page from your desktop.

20 different pictures are displayed on a page and each picture has its own "like" button assigned to it. I can't identify it by "like" and in the outerhtml there are different values for each one. How do I write a script to identify each one?

Here is some of the info on the properties/values.

**class**: `btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton`

**htmlid**: N/a

**htmltag**: Button

**innerhtml:** `<I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like`

**outterhtml (Like button for pic #1):**  `<BUTTON class="btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton" type=button data-target="1194558981914665301_8054519"><I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like</BUTTON>`

**outerhtml (like button for pic#2)**

```
<BUTTON class="btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton" type=button data-target="1194558967727891183_339837919"><I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like</BUTTON>
```

NOTE I listed the outerhtml property values for two different pictures to show where the values differ. This is also the outerhtml code I tried to write to click on any like button and bypass any specific values:*

outerhtml: `<BUTTON class="btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton" type=button data-target=".*_.*"><I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like</BUTTON>`

**This is the script I tried to run that failed**

```
1) systemutil.Run "websta.me/tag/graffiti"; 

2) Browser("#graffiti Instagram photos").Page("#graffiti Instagram photos").WebButton("<BUTTON class="btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton" type=button data-target=".*.*"><I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like</BUTTON> ").Click 

3)wait(1) 

4) Browser("#graffiti Instagram photos").Page("#graffiti Instagram photos").WebButton("<BUTTON class="btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton" type=button data-target=".*.*"><I class="fa fa-heart"></I>Like</BUTTON> ").Click 

5) wait(1)
```

repeat... –

Comment: you can easily use class value for finding collection of objects in this case, check Vinoth S comment on how to do that, just instead of ".*likeButton" (because we dont know how many other objects it will select) put the actual value that you are getting for class i.e btn btn-default btn-xs likeButton

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using `Descriptive programming` approach of QTP

```
Set oDesc = Description.Create
oDesc("micclass").value = "WebButton"
oDesc("html tag").value = "BUTTON"
oDesc("class").value = ".*likeButton"
odesc("class").RegularExpression = True

'Find all the Links
Set obj = Browser().Page().ChildObjects(oDesc)

Msgbox obj.Count  'will show how many buttons are found
For i = 0 to obj.Count - 1              
   Obj(i).Click
   Wait 2  'waits for 2 sec
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VRI (visual relations identifier)](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2012/02/03/qtp-visual-relation-identifier/) to link an ambiguous object (your *like* button) to a well defined object (the picture).

This way you can say *"click the **like** button that's closes to picture X*".

Another way is to create a simple web-extensibility project that exposes a new object for the pictures which support the functionality of *Liking* a picture.